# Transformation that do not modify angles

Tags: matrices, angle

How can I prove for $R_2$ that the matrix $$T = \begin{bmatrix} a & b \\c & d \end{bmatrix} =\begin{bmatrix} a & b \\-b & a \end{bmatrix} $$ is the ony one that, when multiplied with 2 vectors, the angle between them keeps being the same,
$$\frac {(Tv) \cdot (Tu)}{|Tv||Tu|} = \frac {v \cdot u}{|v||u|} = \cos \alpha.$$
If possible I would like to do it only by manipulating this formula

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

Let us look at the action of the matrix on the basis vectors $e_1=\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\end{bmatrix}$ and $e_2=\begin{bmatrix}0\\1\end{bmatrix}$.
$$Te_1=\begin{bmatrix}a\\c\end{bmatrix} \text{ and } Te_2=\begin{bmatrix}b\\d\end{bmatrix}.$$

Since $e_1 \perp e_2$, so for the angle to be preserved, the vectors $Te_1 \perp Te_2$. Thus 
$$ab+cd=0.$$
Moreover, the vectors $Te_1, Te_2$ should be linearly independent.

Hopefully you can take it from here.

Comment: Why $T.v$ and $T.w$ have to be linearly independent?

Comment: @RebecaSilva  I am not saying that in general $Tv$ and $Tw$ have to be linearly independent. But $e_1$ and $e_2$ are basis vectors and $T$ is an angle preserving transformation therefore $\{Te_1, Te_2\}$ will also form a basis (hence linearly independent).

Comment: There is nothing in the problem that states that $T$ should be invertible. So I don't think linear independence of $Te_1,Te_2$ is really something you can assume a priori. That being said, if $T$ singular, and still preserves angles, that puts some serious restrictions on what _kind_ of singular it can be (the exact restriction will depend on how you treat the zero vector)

Comment: @Arthur $T$ is a linear transformation so $T(0)=0$, there is nothing else that $0$ will map to.

Comment: @AnuragA Are your linear transformations defined differently than mine? Because to me, linear transformations can definitely map things other than $0$ to $0$. Or if you're arguing from a "preserves angles" standpoint, then that should in my opinion actually be argued for, not assumed as a triviality.

Comment: @Arthur I hope not because $T(x+y)=T(x)+T(y)$ and $T(\lambda x)=\lambda x$ is what I take as the definition of linear transformation and that definitely gives $T(0)=0$. I hope you are not thinking of affine transformations $T(x)=Ax+b$. Moreover OP's questions is about $T(x)=Ax$, so $T(0)=0$ definitely holds. Thus linear independence of $Te_1, Te_2$ is guaranteed since $T$ preserves the angles between any two non-zero vectors.

Comment: I mean $T(\lambda x)=\lambda T(x)$.

Comment: @AnuragA I agree that $0$ should be sent to $0$. I never said differently. But I'm saying there could be _others_ as well. And if more vectors than just the zero vector are sent to $0$, then $Te_1$ and $Te_2$ aren't linearly independent any more. Note that they can still be _orthogonal_, even though they are linearly dependent, so the angle between them might still be preserved. I'm saying that I think you need a more detailed argument than "$T$ preserves angles, so it is invertible" to show that $T$ is invertible.

Comment: @Arthur if either of $T(e_i)=0$ then the angle between the image vectors $T(e_i)$ is not defined which violates the angle preserving requirement. So both $T(e_i) \neq 0$ and are orthogonal, consequently linearly independent. I don't see anything missing here or any further details needed for justification.

Comment: @AnuragA As I said in my _first_ comment, this depends on how you treat the $0$ vector, and in particular the angle between the $0$ vector and other vectors. There are multiple conventions (one being that the zero vector makes any angle with any other vector, one being that the angle is undefined, one being that the angle is always orthogonal, and possibly others in-between). But what you have there in your last comment is exactly the kind of justification I was asking for.